# Button with image blue background

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I create a button with image in my app:

```
                <Button x:Name="favoriteButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="72" Width="99" Click="DidPressAddToFavorites" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}">
                    <Button.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/favouritesBWIcon@2x.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                    </Button.Background>
                </Button>
```

And i noticed that when the user press the button all the button became blue and when i release the button i see it again. any idea how to fix it?

Edit:

This is the handler method:

```
private void DidPressAddToFavorites(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (favoriteRep.ExistInFavorites(currentItem) == true)
        {
            this.SetButtonWithImage(favoriteButton, "/Images/favouritesBWIcon@2x.png");
            favoriteRep.RemoveFromFavorites(currentItem);
        }
        else
        {
            this.SetButtonWithImage(favoriteButton, "/Images/favouritesIcon@2x.png");
            favoriteRep.AddToFavorites(currentItem);
        }

    }
```

Comment: could you tell us a bit more, or show the code executed on DidPressAddToFavorites ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't add the States, there are three states Normal, MouseOver, Pressed... You have to set the image for all three states, to make it work of your wish. Here the alternate to do so, didn't know about any better way available from c#, all you have to do is to add two more eventHndlers Mouse over event and press event, then set the image in both of them....
Well there's another good way to do so is try template editing from blend Software

Comment: And where i can find this states?